# Blender debugging step problem

Tags: versions

I know this question may not be directly related to Blender, but maybe it does! Please correct if I am wrong!

I can build and step debugging on Blender 2.78 prior to Xcode 8.1, but something get broken since Xcode 8.1, my situation is as follows:

1. build and run blender build from Xcode, following the directions in : https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender/Mac
2. set break point on run_cpu(), and read_node()
3. run blender build, select *cycles render* and select *render mode*
4. it should stop at *both* breakpoints prior to Xcode 8.1,
   while not stop at read_node() since 8.1

My environment is MacOS Sierra.
For completness, the checkout commit is cf8f6d1 from blender git.

Answer (score 1):

For those who also get stuck here --- after trying a week, I get a way to workaround.

Use the Xcode debug window to set command like '**b func**' instead of using the GUI breakpoint (blue arrow) is working.

Obviously it is Xcode to be blamed for.